# Build failed ANT because pdepend is missing

Tags: php, ubuntu, testing, ant, pdepend

I have been trying to set up an **ubuntu** server where ant tests my code. When I start ANT to test my code it starts with phploc-ci that goes fine. But the next check is **pdepend** I get the error Cannot run program "pdepend": error=2, No such file or directory.

As you can see it can't find the path or something. I would say the path is correct because it finds all other folders.

I have been searching this site and google for 2 hours I can't seem to find a solution. Do you guys have any suggestions.

Comment: Either make sure that pdepend is available (install it yourself), or modify your ant script to skip this test.... but ant doesn't magically make those other tools available

Comment: I installed it via pear do you know how to link it ?

Comment: Locate it, and modify the ant script so that it can find it

Comment: have you tried running in debug mode to see more details? - run `ant -deubg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution thanks to a suggestion of Mark Baker. I located every package with sudo find / -xdev 2>/dev/null -name "phpdox" for example after that I copied the patj into value in the build.xml. I did this for every of the needed plugins... now it works